# Merge two tables of two different Sources in Power Pivot

Tags: powerpivot

I have two Data Bases:
1. DB that comes from Access and has the sales info from 2016 and 2017.
2. DB that comes from SQL Server and has the sales info from 2018.

Both DB have exactly the same number and names in the columns.

It is possible to merge this two tables in Power Pivot to get just 1.

Comment: You should be able to merge or append them in the query editor before you load it to your Power Pivot data model.

Comment: But in this case I have to load before in Excel those two tables, and one of them is over 1.5 million rows and it doesn't fit in the Excel worksheet

Comment: Nope, you can have the query editor load both DB sources and chose Close & Load to... and choose Only Create Connection and Add this data to the Data Model.